# Popup menu implementation from NSButton

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How should I go about it?

I was thinking about...

```
[NSMenu popUpContextMenu:menu withEvent:event forView:(NSButton *)sender];
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yup.

On button action call

```
[NSMenu popUpContextMenu:menu withEvent:event forView:(NSButton *)sender];
```

where

- `menu` : menu you want to show
- `sender` : button you clicked
- `event` : a new `NSEvent` you create

When you create the new `NSEvent`, specify the location as to where you want the popup menu to be shown.

Comment: Tried that but the "pop up" menu goes a bit all over the place. I want it to appear exactly BELOW the button (e.g. like the "New Tab","New Window",etc menu in Google Chrome), but this one appears way too... high...

Comment: Ya. As i said above, you can specify the location of popup menu (of where it needs to be shown) while creating the event.

Comment: You can use [[NSApplication sharedApplication] currentEvent] for the event.

Comment: [self.myButton sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask] will make this trigger on mouse down.

Comment: I'd recommend `-[NSMenu popUp:...]` instead of the class method. This way, it will be positioned relative to your button even if you use a keyboard shortcut for it.

Answer (score 19):

Swift version of accepted answer

```
@IBAction func actionOccurred(sender: NSButton) {
    if let event = NSApplication.sharedApplication().currentEvent {
        NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(sender.menu!, withEvent: event, forView: sender)
    }
}
```

---

### Updated answer

Add NSMenu to the NSViewController in the storyboard as seen in the image

[image]

### Connect the Outlet

Right-click on the button in the storyboard and connect the menu outlet to the menu that we have just added to the storyboard(Where arrow points in the image)

[image: jj]

### Add IBAction

```
@IBAction func menuClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    var location = NSEvent.mouseLocation
    location.x -= 10; location.y -= 10 // Menu appears below the button
    let menu = sender.menu!
    menu.popUp(positioning: menu.item(at: 0), at: location, in: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As I have commented I find the ButtonMadness example less than perfect.
My implementation seems to work better. The menu is shown on mouse down, the button remains depressed throughout, the menu position can be specified and the menu is dismissed without subsequent spurious display.

To be honest NSPopupButton is a better choice in the majority of situations. I use this code mainly because of the convenience of having one class for buttons and popups and because the menu does not contain the popup control image and title. I load the menu from a separate nib and reuse it as is elsewhere in the app as required.

Note that it is trivial to add additional support for say a popover as well as menu.

```
NSButton subclass:

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    // if a menu is defined let the cell handle its display
    if (self.menu) {
        if ([theEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDown) {
            [[self cell] setMenu:[self menu]];
        } else {
            [[self cell] setMenu:nil];
        }
    }

    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}

NSButtonCell subclass:

- (BOOL)trackMouse:(NSEvent *)event inRect:(NSRect)cellFrame ofView:(NSView *)controlView untilMouseUp:(BOOL)untilMouseUp
{
    // if menu defined show on left mouse
    if ([event type] == NSLeftMouseDown && [self menu]) {

        NSPoint result = [controlView convertPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMidX(cellFrame), NSMidY(cellFrame)) toView:nil];

        NSEvent *newEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType: [event type]
                                               location: result
                                          modifierFlags: [event modifierFlags]
                                              timestamp: [event timestamp]
                                           windowNumber: [event windowNumber]
                                                context: [event context]
                                            eventNumber: [event eventNumber]
                                             clickCount: [event clickCount]
                                               pressure: [event pressure]];

        // need to generate a new event otherwise selection of button
        // after menu display fails
        [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:[self menu] withEvent:newEvent forView:controlView];

        return YES;
    }

    return [super trackMouse:event inRect:cellFrame ofView:controlView untilMouseUp:untilMouseUp];
}
```

Comment: Works great for me. I've found I can set the menu directly on the cell and not need to subclass the button at all. Am I missing some reason this would be a problem?

Answer (score 6):

Recently, I was trying to implement it and I came, as I think, with a simpler solution

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    NSButton * b = (NSButton*)sender;
    NSPoint l = [ self.window convertBaseToScreen:b.frame.origin ];

    [ self.menu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:l inView:nil ];
}
```

**Update**

`convertBaseToScreen` is deprecated starting from 10.7, instead of it use `convertRectToScreen` in the following way:

```
NSPoint l = [self.window convertRectToScreen:b.frame].origin;
```

Comment: convertBaseToScreen is deprecated since 10_7

Comment: With storyboard (in a ViewController) it doesn't seem to work. I tried without success: `NSPoint point = [[self.view window] convertRectToScreen:((NSButton*)sender).frame].origin;` some idea?

Comment: @Joannes Check that you have set all properly, i.e your action is connected and is being called, self.menu is not nil, self.view.window is not nil. What value(point) do you get ?

Answer (score 4):

Using a context menu on the action call isn't a great way to do it because the menu doesn't show until mouseUp - you don't get the hold & drag menu behavior. Apple's ButtonMadness sample shows how to really do this in a subclass of NSButton, see DropDownButton. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ButtonMadness/Introduction/Intro.html

Summarizing that subclass: create a NSPopUpButtonCell with pullsDown set to YES & preferredEdge to NSMaxYEdge, copy your menu to add a blank top item and set it as that cell's menu, on mouseDown call [thePopUpCell performClickWithFrame:self.bounds inView:self] and set self.needsDisplay

Comment: On 10.8 at least the DropDownButton code is defective. To highlight the issue build the ButtonMadness sample and click the DropDownButton. The menu will display - don't select an item. Now click Radio button 2 - the menu is hidden but the radio item is not selected. So click again, the menu displays again. another click and it hides etc.

Comment: Why do you need to add the blank item? I appreciate that you do (failing to add it truncates the menu) but I can't work out why

Answer (score 2):

Do like that.

```
    -(IBAction)onClickSourceAdd:(id)sender {
       NSMenu *mainMenu = [NSApp mainMenu];
       NSMenu *sourceMenu = [[mainMenu itemAtIndex:2] submenu];
       NSMenu *addMenu = [[sourceMenu itemAtIndex:0] submenu];
       [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:addMenu 
               withEvent:[NSApp currentEvent] 
               forView:(NSButton *)sender]; 
     }
```