# How can we implement custom NSComboBox using NSComboBoxCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscombobox

I am new to OS X. I am trying to implement a drop down using the NSComboBox. I need to customize that, for this, I found NSComboBoxCell component in the storyboard. But did not find the implementation steps for this.

I need to open a drop down list with a label and check box button when the drop down expand.

Can anyone tell me how can we customize the NSComboBoxCell in OS X.

I want to customize the drop down list.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any example about custom NSComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361766/any-example-about-custom-nscombobox)

Comment: draw methods are not implementing custom drop down options, I have tried this link.

Comment: Don't use `NSComboBox`, Use `NSTextField` and a button which shows a window or popover.

Comment: Yes, I have created a custom view acc. to requirements. But I am curious how can we implement NSComboBoxCell in OS X projects. What is the use of it?

Comment: You can use `NSComboBoxCell` in controls where you can replace the cells but these controls are being deprecated.

Comment: but developer.apple is showing that it is implemented in mac OS 10.1 . https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfieldcell

Comment: macOS 10.0 is OS X 10.0 and this is a long time ago.